# Battery consumption using android iBeacon library - short but regular scans

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I only need a rough guide on this really at this point, though specific calculations would obviously be welcome too!

I'm looking at using Radius Network's Android iBeacon Library in an app which will listen for iBeacon advertisements.

I'm new to this but from what I understand it's the scanning for BT devices which is the most battery intensive part of the BLE system so it's not advised to have this running constantly, however I would like to be able to 'catch' devices when they are in a certain area, i.e. a person walking through a lobby.

The Android Beacon Lib's documentation states that the Battery Manager's default setting scans for 30 seconds every 5 minutes (actively scanning for 10% of the time) and this reduces the battery drain on a Nexus 5 from roughly 90mA to 37mA.

My question is... would scanning for 3 seconds every 30 seconds (also 10% of the time) acieve the same battery savings? Or is there an overhead involved in starting the scanning process which would mean the savings would be less? and if so by how much?

Answer (score 2):

You would have to measure to be sure, but I would suspect you would get similar power savings from the cycle you describe (it may be slightly less savings because of startup overhead as you suggest.)

The disadvantage of this approach is that you may miss detections in a 3 second interval, especially in areas with lots of beacons, distant beacons, or with beacons transmitting infrequently.  You have to decide if it is worth the tradeoff.

To test power savings, do the following:

1. On a test device, uninstall as many apps as possible to limit background activity that might use power in unpredicatble ways.
2. Install an app that implements background scanning on the cycle you describe and start it on your device.
3. Charge the battery to 100℅
4. Turn off WiFi and mobile data to prevent system downloads from using power in unpredictable ways.
5. Note the time, turn off the screen, and let the device rest, checking it every hour or so for battery level.
6. When the battery reaches 5%, note the time.
7. Repeat the above test with the app doing a constant scan in the background.

The end result of the above procedure will give you the time it took to drain the battery in both cases.  From this you can calculate the percentage difference in power savings.

Please let us know what you find!

Comment: Great, thanks for your quick answer David. That's kind of what I wanted to hear. In my use case I will have a single beacon and I will have full control over it so will be able to make it transmit/advertise as frequently as is possible (once per second if that's possible) so hopefully the short scans will be long enough to catch the entire advertisement message. I will post back here when I have stats following your above process.

Comment: Hi David. I'm planning to buy a RadBeacon USB dongle to start experimenting with this - could you let me know whether I could set the advertising rate high enough (i.e. at a 1 second interval or lower) on the config app I can see you can set the rate to low medium or high - what's the highest it can go? Battery usage is not an issue as this will be in an AC powered kiosk

Comment: Sean, the default transmission rate is 10Hz. You can dial this down in the config app to 1Hz, but I know of no good reason to do so.

Comment: I'm new to the iBeacon protocol so may have this wrong but my thought was if i increase the advertising rate to as high a frequency as possible then I could write an android app which uses short but regular scans (as above) and this would hopefully achieve both lower battery usage but also the ability to pick up the beacon. You mentioned in your answer the disadvantage of short but regular scans would be potentially missing detections of the beacon. Would increasing the advertising rate not fix this issue? Or am I missing something?

Comment: The issue is that infrequently transmitting beacons (e.g. 1Hz) may only have one transmission fully in a 3 second window.  This is because the other two transmissions may straddle the boundary of the 3 second scan starting and stopping.   If radio noise or interference causes this one remaining by transmission to be missed, the system would think the beacon was invisible when it bus not.  Longer scan periods make this much less likely.

Comment: Adding numbers to my above comment: previous tests have shown that a 3sec scan intervals misses detecting beacons transmitting at 1 Hz 14% of the time.  See here: https://github.com/RadiusNetworks/android-ibeacon-service/blob/2bf8414c29c33399a00bccca5eafe2b42df5dccd/src/com/radiusnetworks/ibeacon/service/IBeaconService.java#L84